# Jquery click not working on mobile devices and Chrome toolbar

Tags: javascript, jquery

Click event works fine for tablet but it doesn't work for mobile.

```
html += '<button class="box box-'+(i)+'" data-content="'+(i+1)+'">'+ 
(i+1)+'</button>';
$('._container').html(html);

$('.box').on('click',function () {
alert(1);
});
```

I had also tried with 'touchstart' but no luck.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lh5dry8p/) works good on mobile,tablet and pc but why this code isn't working on my app

Comment: @Mohammad I have successfully attached event to my dynamic element.. Problem is event is working for tablet and PC but not for mobile

Comment: Check `touchstart` for mobile

Comment: I had also tried with 'touchstart' and 'mouseenter' but no luck.

Comment: Your code has additional parentheses `(function()`. It is typo in snippet or in your code?

Comment: still not working

Comment: What mobile are you testing on and what is the mobile browser?

Comment: guys thanks ! issue is resolved ! There was a problem of CSS..